# Error Rendering a React Element

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a selection from a drop-down, query movies based on the selected value, `map` through and render them inside a react component but I got this error

> A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Here's the code:

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { description: '', list: [] }
}

handleList() {
  axios.get('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then(resp => this.setState({...this.state, list: resp.data})) // Trás a lista atualizada e zera a descrição
    console.log(this.state.list)
}


render() {
    const loop = this.state.list.map((list) => {
    return(
        <Grid cols='2'>
                <select className="form-control" key={i}>
                    <option value="teste" onClick={() => this.handleList()}>{list.description}</option>
                    <option value="lime">Lime</option>
                    <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
                    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
                </select>
        </Grid>
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of issues with this code example.

1. You are not returning anything inside the `render()` function. (This is the main issue you are having, or at least that React is crying about)
2. You are, well at least initially, mapping over an empty array and
3. The callback of this map you are doing things like `list.description` even though there exists no `list` and no `description` inside of `list` during the initial render.
4. You are using the `onClick` for the `option`s instead of `onChange`
5. The endpoint you are requesting returns an object and you try to map through it. This should error because `map` is not defined as a function of an object.

I have managed to fix the issues I have mentioned including the one you are currently having. To save energy, typing the long explanation and reason that went into fixing your issue, have a look at this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/af-react-sandbox-bcnrsg). It contains the exact same code you have posted, but of course, fixed/working.

Comment: thanks for the answer and explanation I'm starting with react I still have a lot to learn but it worked out fine

Answer (score 0):

I think `onclick` event is not suitable to use in `option`. Better use it on `select`

```
` <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
    <option value="lime">Lime</option>
    <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
    <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  </select>
`

Sicne you are rendering a list of forms to reuse the same function, I always use a closure

    handleChange = (id) = () =>  axios
      .get(`$URL/id`)
      .then(r => r.data)
      .then(this.setState)

    render() {
      return (
        list.map(item => <select 
               key={item.id}
               onChange={this.handleChange(item.id)}
             >
                 <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
                 <option value="lime">Lime</option>
                 <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
                 <option value="mango">Mango</option>
             </select>))}
```